# Using the Dir function in a Do While Loop (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

Help with using the Dir function in VBA in a Do While Loop

Basically I am trying to find the most recent version of a file in a directory to use elsewhere in the macro. The filepath for these is "A:\HOLD\ReportName-" & the report date in "mmddyy" format, followed by a random series of characters our ERP produces. So for example "A:\HOLD\ReportName-081220-asdknrtr884"

I want the program to look for a file from today, and if that does not exist to keep looking back day by day until it finds a file (up to 30 days). So 081220, 081120, 081020, etc.

The problem is that the Do While Loop is only looking back one day before going into an infinite loop and hitting the 30 day max, even when files exist within that time-frame.

From what I have gathered it has something to do with the Dir() function, and how it keeps the filepath value. I just have not seen a good answer to my particular situation, mostly answers to when Dir <> "" or Len > 0.

Thanks for any help!

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
    
Dim FilePath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim FullFile As String
Dim FileDate As String
Dim strFileExists As String
Dim count As Integer
    
FilePath = "A:\HOLD\"
FileDate = Format(Date, "mmddyy")
FileName = "ReportName-" & FileDate & "*"
FullFile = FilePath & FileName
    
strFileExists = Dir(FullFile)
    
Do While strFileExists = ""
    FileDate = Format(Date - 1, "mmddyy")
    FileName = "ReportName-" & FileDate & "*"
    FullFile = FilePath & FileName
    strFileExists = Dir(FullFile)
    count = count + 1

    If count > 30 Then
        MsgBox "There has not been a report in over 30 days, please run a new report"
        Exit Do     
        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(FullFile)

'''
```

Comment: `FileDate = Format(Date - 1, "mmddyy")` - how do you expect this to change on each iteration of your loop?  This will only ever be `Date - 1`, or yesterday's date. You need to establish a variable equal to today's date, then subtract 1 day from it in each iteration.

Comment: Yes this was it, now I feel like an idiot. Was chasing the Dir() function down into a rabbit hole and completely overlooked the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
        
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FullFile As String
    Dim FileDate As String
    Dim strFileExists As String
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    
    FilePath = "A:\HOLD\"
    FileDate = Format(Date, "mmddyy")
    FileName = "ReportName-" & FileDate & "*"
    FullFile = FilePath & FileName
        
    strFileExists = Dir(FullFile)
    count = 1
    
    Do While strFileExists = ""
        FileDate = Format(Date - count, "mmddyy")
        FileName = "ReportName-" & FileDate & "*"
        FullFile = FilePath & FileName
        strFileExists = Dir(FullFile)
        count = count + 1
    
        If count > 30 Then
            MsgBox "There has not been a report in over 30 days, please run a new report"
            Exit Do
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Loop
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(FullFile)

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, I am an idiot and spent hours looking in the wrong place. Thank you!

Comment: Common mistake! Good luck